# Laravel date_format rule not working

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, format, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use a datetime format rule for my input like this:

```
H:i:s
```

My model rule looks like this:

```
    public static $rules = [
        ...
        'start'    => [
            'min:8',
            'date_format:"H:i:s"',
        ],
    ];
```

And in my controller I call it like this:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Product::$rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
```

If I `dd($validator)` I get following:

```
  #rules: array:7 [▼
     ...
    "start" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "min:8"
      1 => "date_format:"H:i:s""
    ]
  ]
```

I insert 00:h:01 into the input field but I did not get any error message.

Comment: What if you change 'date_format:"H:i:s"' to 'date_format:H:i:s'? So you don't escape the format.

Comment: Still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'min:8' and then test again

```
 public static $rules = [
        ...
        'start'    => [
            'date_format:"H:i:s"',
        ],
    ];
```

FYI, Laravel date_format rule internally use date_parse_from_format() for validation

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

I have just checked and it worked for me:

```
print_r(date_parse_from_format("H:i:s", "00:h:01"));
```

Comment: did `print_r(date_parse_from_format("H:i:s", "00:h:01"));` return true or false?

Comment: No it won't, it will return you an array, and if there will be errors then it will inside of that array